# PHP - $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] empty

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an index page on my server, when I request host.com/?123

```
 echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // returns 123 as expected
```

but if I perform an request without the '?' character: host.com/123
QUERY_STRING always stays empty in this case.

but I'm not sure how do I need to configure .htaccess to be able to read the query,

How can I get it to read the full request URL? Thanks!

Comment: short answer `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This makes it so when you request `/abcd1234`, your script should see "abcd1234" as the query string.

This single rule has 2 conditions, `!-f` which checks that the request isn't for an existing file, and `!-d` which checks that the request isn't for an existing directory. If both are met, then the request is simply rewritten as the query string.